# how to automatically run mongorestore after a mongodump

Tags: mongodb, docker

I have a MongoDB container running the latest version of the database, and I can manually use the mongodump command to download my data in production and later run mongorestore to insert this data into a local container.

Then I thought: Oh, if I just mongodump --things && mongorestore --otherthings then the mongorestore command will be run after the mongodump command.

[image: Commands run together fail]

However, the mongodump command (at least inside the container shell) is a little tricky, since mongodump doesn't *lock* the shell, and I think as soon as I hit enter, mongorestore command gets activated too since it thinks that mongodump has finished. Then, mongorestore completed with failures since there is no data downloaded yet. After a couple of seconds mongodump *STARTS* downloading the files and the shell gets locked. Even after the files are completely downloaded, the shell doesn't get unlocked and I can't type new commands unless I hit enter.

[image: Command doesn't 'lock' terminal]
[image: When download is complete, command doesn't unlock the terminal]
[image: After a key press, the terminal lock is released]

So my question is: How do I run one single script (.sh file or something) that can wait for mongodump to finish, and only then execute the mongorestore command?)

Comment: Use a pipe: `mongodump --archive --db=test | mongorestore --archive  --nsFrom='test.*' --nsTo='examples.*'` see https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/program/mongorestore/#copy-clone-a-database or https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/135478/large-mongodump-followed-by-mongorestore

Comment: Same result happens :/

Comment: Same problem here. Since mongodump does not "lock" the terminal. The next shell script run instantly after the mongodump trigger. I wish to copy the file elsewhere after mongodump finish but fail

Answer (score 0):

I encounter the same problem but found that the mongodump is able to "lock" the terminal finally after adding double quote `""` to your mongodump

i.e. something like `mongodump --uri="mongodb://localhost:27017" --gzip --archive="backup.gz"`